# Is the maximum a task difficulty can be eased 4 without applying Effort?

Tags: numenera, difficulty

The rules on task resolution are stated below:

> A character’s level of skill is either trained
>   (reasonably skilled) or specialized (very skilled). 
>   If you are trained in a skill relating to a task,
>   you ease the difficulty of that task by one step.
>   If you are specialized, you ease the difficulty
>   by two steps. A skill can never ease a task’s
>   difficulty by more than two steps.
>   Anything else that reduces difficulty (help from an
>   ally, a particular piece of equipment, or some other
>   advantage) is referred to as an asset. Assets can
>   never ease a task’s difficulty by more than two steps.
>   You can also ease the difficulty of a given
>   task by applying Effort. (Effort is described in
>   more detail in Chapter 8: Rules of the Game.)
>   To sum up, three things can ease a task’s
>   difficulty: skills, assets, and Effort.
>
> *Numenera Discovery. Pg. 15*

Does this mean that there is no means through which to ease a task by more than 4 if one does not utilize Effort?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per rules-as-written, this is correct.

Discovery discusses the three ways of easing a task on page 103:

### Skills:

> Skills can never ease a task by more than two steps — any more than two
>   steps from being trained and specialized don’t count.

### Assets:

> Assets can never ease a task by more than two steps — any more than
>   two steps from assets don’t count.

### and Effort:

> Eﬀort can never ease a task by more than six steps — any more than six
>   steps from applying Eﬀort doesn’t count.

So, yes, four steps is the most you can reduce a task's level by, without applying Effort.

Comment: Curiously, there are 3 instances in Discovery where a task is eased by 3 steps (Stim cypher, Focuses Mind over Matter focus abilities)